# How to make an object in the animation influencing visibility of another object

Tags: animation, objects, shaders, transparency, visibility

This is my first post and I was searching for my answer on the forum but could not come up with a solution.

I have an animation where I show how the biopsy probe penetrates the brain to reach a tumor cells. I am using layers and compositing to show outliner of a transparent brain and tumor cells on top of the human head. When I render image with the probe inserted in the brain it is hidden in the head and not showing in the transparent brain. When I add new layer with the probe and put on top of the head, and under the transparent brain it look good for the penetration of the brain and tumor, but it is also on top of the head. Is there a way to use the transparent brain object or its copy to make the probe visible in render only when it heats this object? So basically my object will be shown only when it interacts with the other object.

Thank you for any tips in advance.

Charles

Answer (score 0):

A picture of what you're trying to achieve could help, so here's my answer according to my understanding.

You could you use a three planes/object configuration to mimic the probe entering the tissues such as in the screenshots below, either in the 3D editor or in the Compositor with layers and masks:

[image]
[image]
[image]